# Zener Regulator is not Working as Designed

Tags: voltage-regulator, zener

I have a small load which runs on 3.3V, and I want to regulate the input from a 5V USB micro cable, same as used for phone chargers and similar.

[image]

The load is a MCU with LCD and backlight, plus some other small circuits.  When fully running, it draw about 89mA. When idle, it draws about 77.5mA.

So at full load, I can't drop more that 1.7V over the resistor.   Which yields a max value of 19 ohms.

The diode(s) I tested with are 1N5226B.  I tried several, and they all behave similar.

[image]

The Zener is rated at 500mW, so that is a max avalanche of 151mA, which sets the low end of the resistor at 11.25 ohms.  Vmin and Vmax are manufacturing differences across batches as I understand it, not varying ranges within a single diode.

I used a 16 ohm resistor to "split the difference".  I should see 3.3V across the load and diode with the MCU power off, as well as when the MCU is on.  And Iz of 20mA means the overall current should be about 110mA, well within the safe range. ( What is Zz?  I can't find any description of it. )

However, that is not the behavior I am seeing.

Under full load, I am getting 3.27V across the diode, and 3.368 under light load. The output is "close enough" to 3.3V, but this seems like an excessive variance.

With the load removed, the circuit is still sinking 79mA, and the diode is 3.65V. That's an error of over 10%.  When I increase the supply to 5.1V, the voltage across the diode increases to 3.67V.  That's a 20mV increase for a 100mV change, or 20%

In fact, when I tested with a 20 ohm resistor, and a 11 ohm resistor, the unloaded voltage was always in the 3.6 range.

These seem a bit severe.  Am I missing something?  What concerns me is the inrush when the circuit is turned on.  3.6V is a bit higher than I'd like to have slammed into the MCU/Display  (this is an "add on" so the power switch is down stream, and removes the load from the circuit by the user).

Comment: See this: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/174471/3v6-zener-diodes-with-very-poor-accuracy   Good information farther down.

Comment: Seems normal to me for such a huge zener current change. For 5V to 3v3 I would use a TL431+NPN follower.

Comment: I agree that people do not use a zener diode as a circuit voltage regulator anymore.

Comment: can you add a cap across the zener to prevent the power on spike (as seen by the mcu)? you could also use 2 zeners in parallel to lower heat creep and flatten I/V.

Comment: I wanted to consider a Zener because I have only been able to find beefy TO220 3.3V regulators.  I had hoped to be creative, minimal, plus reduce size and cost.

Answer (score 3):

It is unclear what exactly you expect from the Zener but it is unlikely to provide what you expect.

The zener data sheet is clear on this, the voltage over the zener is 3.3V +/- 5% when there is exactly 20mA through the zener.

If current is more or less then the voltage over the zener won't be 3.3V +/- 5%. The zener has impedance of 28 ohms at that bias point, so each 1mA difference in current means 28mV voltage difference.

To expand on that, it roughly means 10mA difference in current means 0.28V difference, and since you want to limit 3.3V from rising above 3.6V or by 0.3V, it means the current through zener may not change from 20mA more than about 10.7mA to 30.7mA, assuming the zener impedance even holds for such large deviations from 20mA.

If you want regulated voltage over a load current difference over 10mA, this is not a proper zener for that.

In practice, as the zener can have initial tolerance of 3.465V at 20mA, it means the voltage can't rise more than 0.135V so the current can't rise from 20mA by even 4.8mA, or 24%, to keep voltage below 3.6V.

Use a regulator.

Comment: Thanks.  That is what I was looking for.  The data sheet had no details or graphs to set my expectations.

Answer (score 3):

"With the load removed, the circuit is still sinking 79mA, and the diode is 3.65V."
With the load removed, the zener is now drawing about 84 mA (1.35/16), but when the load was there the zener was drawing about 20 or 30 mA. The increase in zener current produces an increase in zener voltage.
The key is Zz. This is the dynamic impedance of the zener. It reflects the relationship between voltage and current for small variations around the nominal  operating point. You can model the zener as a resistance in series with a voltage source in series with a blocking diode which only allows current to flow it the input is greater than the nominal zener voltage.
in this case, Zz is 28 ohms. An increase of 50 mA through 28 ohms will cause a variation of nominally 1.4 volts.
This suggests, as Justme stated, that you are way outside the operating range where the zener will behave well. His rule of thumb, keeping the zener current within +/- 50% of the nominal current is a good one.
Get a beefier zener.

Comment: Good description for Zz  I hadn't found that anywhere else.